# Fetch all views in oracle db along with details like number of rows,columns, primary keys etc

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I'm trying to write a query for **retrieving all the views in oracle database along with number of rows, columns and primary keys of each view.**

i tried 'all_views', but it doesn't give what i need.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Views don't have primary keys, as they can be based on multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

`all_views` tells you the name of the views (that you have access to, there may be more in the system).  `all_tab_columns` will give you the names of the columns.  As @GerardH.Pille points out, views do not have primary keys.  You'd need to run a `select` against each view in turn to determine the number of rows it can return (remembering that a view could have logic that filters by a session variable, a context, or some other session-specific setting) so that different users or different sessions may get different results.  That could get rather expensive depending on your system.